# How to use external native library in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to learn NDK, and I'd like to use external library (libopus). After reading some articles, I got these steps:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libopus
mv libopus jni
NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. ndk-build
```

It crated `libs/armeabi/libopus.so` file. Yay, awesome! ... And now what? How can I use this library? How can I call its functions and methods?

Also, will my app run on non-ARM architectures (x86, MIPS), because `armeabi` suggests it'll be ARM only.

Comment: https://github.com/tbocek/opus-wrapper   libopus is a pretty complex place to startup with ndk because at the interface level you also have to dive into media streams and thread handlers for those streams along with the pointers/references to functions operating on the media streams.

Answer (score 1):

You can not just use standard Linux libraries. Java/Android uses the Java Native Interface (JNI) which is special C code that builds the bridge between Java part and native part.

It looks like you already have NDK installed. Look into the project samples, e.g. the "hello-jni" project. In this example you can see what JNI C code you have to write and how to access the self written functions from within your Java code.

Regarding the architectures: Yes, an ARM library is for the ARM platform only. If you want to create a cross-platform App you have to compile all native libraries for each supported platform (usually ARM, ARMv7, x86 and MIPS).

Comment: So I'll have to write some additional wrapper in C which will enable opus functions to Java?

Comment: If there is not already an existing wrapper or a "Java binding" sub-project of the library you want to use, yes.